# Syntax of Vars in VBA with SQL

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

in my Job I have a Little Problem with VBA (I'am new to VBA, so it is maybe only a Little fault, but I haven't found a solution in the Internet)

```vb
    For i = 0 To Me!Liste_Eingangsdiagnostik.ListCount - 1
    diagName = Me!Liste_Eingangsdiagnostik.column(0, i) & "_" & Me!Liste_Eingangsdiagnostik.column(1, i) & "_" & 1


    If Me!Liste_Eingangsdiagnostik.Selected(i) Then
    buildFilter_EingangsDiag i
    tableName = Me!Liste_Eingangsdiagnostik.column(0, i)
    Debug.Print tableName
    newColumn = "ALTER TABLE " & tempTable & " ADD COLUMN " & tableName & " " & "Long"
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("abf_Export_Diagnostik") 'Erstelle die Antworten

    'updateExport = "INSERT INTO Export_Hilfstabelle " & " (IDTAB_EP, ID_Antwortbogen, tableName) " & " (rs.Fields(1).Value,rs.Fields(1).Value,.Fields(1).Value)"

    db.Execute newColumn

        Do While Not rs.EOF
        a = rs.Fields("IDTAB_EP").value
        Debug.Print a
        b = rs.Fields("ID_Antwortbogen").value
        Debug.Print b
        c = rs.Fields("strAntworten_Text").value
        Debug.Print c

        db.Execute "INSERT INTO [Export_Hilfstabelle] " & " ([IDTAB_EP], [ID_Antwortbogen], [ID_Frage], ['" & tableName & "']) VALUES " & " ('" & a & "', '" & b & "',0,'" & c & "')"
        rs.MoveNext
        Loop

    End If
Next i
```

The Users of this Database want all their Diagnostics they choose in one Table. So I try to add for every Diagnostic a new column (tableName), but I got the ErrorLog: the field Name ist not correct.
(I'm from Germany, so some Vars are in German.)
Thank you very much for yout help!

Comment: Which line do you get that error on?  the `ALTER TABLE` or the `INSERT INTO`?

Comment: The INSERT INTO throws the Error.

Comment: In the INSERT statement, the apostrophes in `['" & tableName & "']` are wrong, remove them. But that's probably not the only problem. -- See also: [How to debug dynamic SQL in VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/418960/managing-and-debugging-sql-queries-in-ms-access/1099570#1099570)

Comment: Thanks, Andre! It works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The columns list in the INSERT statement must not have apostrophes.

```
db.Execute "INSERT INTO [Export_Hilfstabelle] " & 
  " ([IDTAB_EP], [ID_Antwortbogen], [ID_Frage], ['" & tableName & "']) 
  VALUES " & " ('" & a & "', '" & b & "',0,'" & c & "')"
```

should be

```
db.Execute "INSERT INTO [Export_Hilfstabelle] " & 
  " ([IDTAB_EP], [ID_Antwortbogen], [ID_Frage], [" & tableName & "]) 
  VALUES " & " ('" & a & "', '" & b & "',0,'" & c & "')"
```